# What is the probability of guessing the right number $n$ from all numbers $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: probability, infinity

As we all know, $\mathbb{N}$ contains infinitely many numbers. What is the probability of guessing the right number $n \in \mathbb{N}$, i. e. what is $\frac{1}{\infty}$? It is clear that there is a chance of guessing the right number but it is very unlikely.

Comment: There is no uniform probability on the natural numbers - there is no way to "choose a random natural number" so that all are equally likely.

Comment: @Thomas could you not do this with a limit? eg: to pick $k$ out of a set with $n$ items is $\frac{1}{n}$ then to pick it out of a countably infinite set would just be $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$ ?

Comment: @Ben the limit doesn't work as a probability measure, although it can give a density function.

Comment: In particular, the problem is that a probability measure needs to be "countably additive." That means the $p(n)$ can't be zero for all $n$ because $1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty p(n)$. On the other hand, if $p(n)=p>0$ for all $n$ then $\sum_n p(n)$ does not converge.

Comment: Linguistically, are all those numbers given an agreed on naming structure?  For example, what is a million raised to the 100th power called?  Is this the same for everyone?  Something to ponder here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"It is clear that there is a chance of guessing the right number" It becomes less clear the more you think about it.  Can you imagine any kind of physical process which could, even in principle, return any natural number with positive probability (let alone equal probability)?

This is an example of why mathematicians have resorted to reasoning axiomatically when it comes to the infinite: intuition is often not up to the task.  In this case it is easy to see that it is impossible to set things up in a coherent, nontrivial way.  Namely:

Suppose we want to assign a non-negative "probability" to every subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$.  What properties do we want?  Surely at least the following:

$\bullet$ for all subsets $X$ of $\mathbb{N}$, $0 \leq P(X) \leq 1$.
$\bullet$ For all $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$, $P(\{x\}) = P(\{y\})$.
$\bullet$ For any disjoint subsets $X$ and $Y$, $P(X \cup Y) = P(X) + P(Y)$.

From these we quickly deduce that for every *finite* subset $X$ of $\mathbb{N}$, 
$P(X) = 0$.  Namely, suppose $P(\{1\}) = \alpha > 0$.  There is some natural number $n$ 
such that $\frac{1}{n} < \alpha$, and then $P( \{1,\ldots,n\}) = n \alpha > 1$: oops!

Decreeing that every finite set has probability zero is thus far consistent but not a very interesting answer (at least not if you only care about finite sets!). Moreover, note how little we asked for: in modern mathematics to speak of "probabilities" at all one usually requires also

$\bullet$ $P(\mathbb{N}) = 1$.
$\bullet$ If $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ then $P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n)$.

But now these axioms are strictly contradictory: we get

$1 = P(\mathbb{N}) = P( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{n\}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\{n\}) = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 0 = 0$.

Note: in view of the above, something's gotta give.  From a mathematical perspective the best thing to do is throw away the second axiom that all singleton sets arise with equal probability.  Thus you can endow the natural numbers with a perfectly good "probability measure" by choosing an infinite sequence $p_n$ of non-negative real numbers with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n = 1$ -- e.g. we could take $p_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$.  Then for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we put $P(\{n\}) = p_n$, and for any subset $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ we put $P(S) = \sum_{n \in S} P(\{n\})$.  Such "discrete probability measures" can be quite useful in mathematics...but they do not formalize the romantic allure of picking a positive integer at random.

Comment: There is definitely a process that can return a random positive integer and can return any such value. Flip a fair coin until you get a tails. Return the number of tosses. This terminates with probability 1. It just doesn't get an equal probability across all of $\mathbb N$:it returns $n$ with probability $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: @Thomas: Two problems: (i) terminating with probability $1$ is often regarded as being mathematically equivalent to always terminating, but it's not the same.  (ii) Do you actually believe that it is possible, even in principle, to make $10^{10^{100}}$ tosses?  If so you have some very nonstandard physical ideas.

Comment: OK, good answer. The equiprobable selection seems to be an intuitive argument. When humans select numbers they usually only considers very small numbers, usually smaller than let's say $10^{10}$. Nobody would ever consider a number like $10^{232141155453245324324324532}$.

Comment: @Thomas: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  (If you're saying that a set with positive probability must be nonempty: clearly true.  If you're saying that a set that has zero probability must be empty: clearly false.  Are you saying either of these things or something else?)

Comment: Ah, I misread your complaint (ii). You wrote in your question, " Can you imagine any kind of physical process which could, even in principle,..." My proposed random natural number does "in principle" select a random natural number. Obsessing about the possibility of picking a random number is misdirection, because it is also not physically possible to pick a random real number in $[0,1]$ with anything like uniformity, yet mathematicians talk about doing so all the time. $\mathbb N$ is different because it is countable, not because it is infinite.

Comment: You can also drop the countable additivity axiom and get a "probability measure" that is much closer to the intuitive notion of a uniform probability measure on the natural numbers.

Comment: @Thomas: I think I should retract my first objection: just because it is possible that you could flip the coin forever does not mean that it couldn't terminate with any natural number of flips; indeed for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ the latter event is, relatively speaking, infinitely more probable than the former.  My point though was that if you think that you can in principle flip a coin forever, your principles are quite antithetical to physical reality.  By the way, my arguments are meant to motivate a purely mathematical, Kolmogorov style approach to probability, not denigrate it.

Comment: I didn't say I could flip a coin forever in principle, I said I could get any number in principle, since it terminates with probability (1). I don't need to flip a coin forever.

Comment: And you are missing my point, because the "principle" of such random number generation is confusing at best. By the principle, it is impossible to pick a random number from $[0,1]$ which is uniform, and yet we define a uniform probability space on that set all the time. The problem with $\mathbb N$ is not that it is infinite. The obsession with having a physical process will actually mislead the poster.

Comment: @Thomas: replace "flipping forever" with "For every natural number $n$, it is possible to flip a coin $n$ times."  The latter, weaker statement, is almost certainly false for all sufficiently large $n$, as long as we are talking about actual coins and people.  Does this stop us from making mathematical models of the infinite?  Of course not; I did so in my answer.

Comment: My point was that the OP seemed to be proceeding from the assumption that questions about probabilities on infinite sets are inherently meaningful: "it is clear that there is a chance of guessing the right number".  But infinite sets are in fact not something we meet in our everyday lives, so our everyday intuitions about them are far from trustworthy.  Hence the switch to a more abstract, purely mathematical thinking where we enumerate our assumptions explicitly.  I don't see why this is misleading, but if you think it is maybe you should leave an answer of your own.